# Having error in sign up and sign in for blogging websites

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all, I'm a beginner so, I don't know much but, I expect you would help me.
I've made a website for blogging where you sign up and it redirects you to the main page. Here it should tell me if I already signed up once.

I should get an alert if I have signed up before and it should check pass but, here I am not getting it like that. In fact, it redirects even if I have entered the wrong password for the username.
I don't know why this happens...

Signup.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href= "blog.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page title</title>
</head>
<body>  
<div class="Title" align="center"> 
       <br>     
       <hr>
       <h1> InFinite Blogging</h1>
       <hr>
       <br>       
   </div> 
   </div> 
    <form id="form" action="signup.html" method="post">
  <div class="signup">
      <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="username">
      <br>
      <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="password" >
      <button id="next" onclick="check()">sign up </button>
 </div> 
   </form>
  <script src="blog.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Blog.js :

```
var avail = false;
localStorage.setItem(0, 'admin');
localStorage.setItem('admin', '12345678');

function check() {
    var user = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var max1 = Object.keys.length;
    var max = Object.keys.length-1;

    if( user == "" || user== null || pass ==""|| pass==null ) {
        alert("enter your name and password, first.");
        document.getElementById('username').focus;
        document.getElementById('password').focus;
        return false;
    } else if(pass.length<8) {
        alert("Password must contain 8 characters.");
        document.getElementById('username').focus;
        document.getElementById('password').focus;
        return false;  
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
            if (user == localStorage.getItem(i)) {
                alert("it looks like you already have account .");
                avail=true;
                PASS = localStorage.getItem(user);

                if (pass!=PASS) {
                    alert("Please, check your password and write correctly.");
                } else if(pass==PASS) {
                    avail='correct';
                }         
            } 
    
        }
    
        if(avail!=true) {
            localStorage.setItem(max1, user)
            localStorage.setItem(user, pass)
            document.getElementById("form").action = 'main.html';
        } else if(avail=='correct') {
            document.getElementById("form").action = 'main.html';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't double-space your code, it means lots of unnecessary scrolling.

Comment: What is `Object.keys.length` supposed to be? `Object.keys` is a function, you need to call it with an object as the argument. I think you mean `Object.keys(localStorage).length`

Comment: "I just want you to check my code and tell me where I should change things." -> Go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get your code reviewed. I removed this and moved your actual question to the top. Also removed the main.html code.

Comment: And, of course, welcome to SO! Your goal should be to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: No @Christian , broken code is [not ready for review](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) until it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(avail == false){
localStorage.setItem(max1, user)               
localStorage.setItem(user, pass)
document.getElementById("form").action = 'main.html';}
```

or

```
else if(pass==PASS) {
confirmed='correct';
}
```

There are 2 possible solutions:

- check for `if(avail == false)`
- use another variable when the password has been confirmed.

By redeclaring `avail = "correct"`, you are changing the `typeof(avail)` from boolean to string. Avail will never be true because it's no longer a boolean.

Comment: *"Avail will never be true"* That's not true. If it finds the user and the password is wrong, it will be.